# In some situations, Babel does not transform 'import' statement

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, commonjs

The one-line file:

```
export * from 'a.js'
```

is transformed to:

```
'use strict';

import _Object$defineProperty from 'babel-runtime/core-js/object/define-property';
import _Object$keys from 'babel-runtime/core-js/object/keys';
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
...
```

The funny part of this is the `import ...` statement, which obviously fails (in browser environment). I'm including `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` plugin (both explicitly and implicitly in `es2015` preset) but it somehow fails to transform the `import` statement (it works in the rest of the app). Am I doing something wrong? Is this an error in the ecosystem of babel plugins?

I played with multiple .babelrc settings (plugin ordering, explicit / implicit commonjs plugin, ...) but the result is still the same. Sample `.babelrc` setting

```
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime", "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"],
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
```

I'm using the newest versions of the plugins.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Have you tried reporting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can split it into two steps,

```
import a from 'a.js'
export default a;
```